# How to set Alignment in NSMutableAttributedString iOS Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, alignment, nsmutableattributedstring

I want to change **alignment** of my html in **iOS Swift 3 Xcode 8.3**.
Every things works correctly but i do not know about alignment **[image: attributes]**.
My code like this:

```
extension String {
    func htmlAttributedString() -> NSAttributedString? {
        guard let data = self.data(using: String.Encoding.utf16, allowLossyConversion: false) else { return nil }

        let style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        style.alignment = NSTextAlignment.center


        guard let html = try? NSMutableAttributedString(
            data: data,
            options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType,NSTextAlignment:.center],
            documentAttributes:nil) else { return nil }


        return html
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason of getting the error is that `options` parameter is a dictionary of type: `[String : Any]`, passing `NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute` (String) and `NSTextAlignment` (Int) is illegal (dictionaries are strongly typed).

The solution would be to use [`NSMutableParagraphStyle`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/nsmutableparagraphstyle) and add it as an option; You are already declared one and set its alignment to `.center`, but you are not using it!

You should add it with `NSParagraphStyleAttributeName` key (instead of `NSTextAlignment`), as follows:

```
extension String {
    func htmlAttributedString() -> NSAttributedString? {
        guard let data = self.data(using: String.Encoding.utf16, allowLossyConversion: false) else { return nil }

        let style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        style.alignment = NSTextAlignment.center

        guard let html = try? NSMutableAttributedString(
            data: data,
            options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType,
                      NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: style],

            documentAttributes:nil) else { return nil }

        return html
    }
}
```

Note that `NSParagraphStyleAttributeName` data type is String, which means that the data type of the options `dictionary` would be -legally- `[String : Any]`.